# ReactJS: Toggle class for css transition

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I need to toggle on a css class after a component (or even the page) is completely rendered, so that relevant properties are animated on page load.

How do I go about doing this, preferably without jQuery?

If I toggle a component's class in `componentDidMount`, the animation doesn't actually happen.

Comment: Please provide a minimum example or piece of code, so we can provide a better answer that will be a useful resource in the future...

Comment: .toggleClass? http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Whats the question ?

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that I'm using react!

Comment: fyi take a look into the ReactCSSTransitionGroup, might be useful http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I didnt actually get the part where you say:

> after a component (or even the page) is completely rendered, so that
>   relevant properties are animated on page load.

When exactly do you want to animate the element ? If you specify the class name in render() function the component will be rendered with animation on page load.

If you want to control/toggle animation after first render, you can control the class name using component state like so:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            condition:false
        }
    },

    handleClick :function(){
        this.setState( { condition : !this.state.condition } );
    },

    render: function() {
        return <div>
                <div className={this.state.condition ? "animated" :""}  >Hello {this.props.name}</div>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Change Condition</button>

               </div>;
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.body);
```

Here I changed the state in response to a button click. You may probably want to change this to some other event you like.

Here is a fiddle for the above code : http://jsfiddle.net/f0j4kt0L/

Comment: So what I want to do is load the animation immediately after the page is loaded. I've tried exactly what you've suggested, but instead changing the `this.state.condition` in the componentDidMount method. The css class is applied immediately in that case, with no transition.

Comment: What happens when you change this line: '<div className="animated">Hello {this.props.name}</div>' ?  Doesn't it just work on page load: http://jsfiddle.net/3fmfous3/ ?

Comment: this was a super helpful demonstration. really clarified it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using toggle class as well.

```
var node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.el);
node.classList.toggle('menu-open');
```

Comment: I would say this not the react way of doing stuff.